# How to run gatling from multiple git repositories

Tags: java, scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

i am working on a gatling project. i need to configure gatling on jenkins to run read tests from different repositories.

by examples:

I have 2 projects on git, project A and project B which contain performance tests.

i want to create a gatling project to configure on the jenkins pipeline to read the performance tests which are on repository A and B

Comment: and what did you do so far?
please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look something like this:

```
node {
    stages {
      stage ('repo A run') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/org/repoA'
        withMaven {
          sh "mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=..."
        } 
      }
      stage ('repo B run') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/org/repoB'
        withMaven {
          sh "mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=..."
        } 
      }
    }
}
```